# how to set HTTP only flag in XAMPP

Tags: php, session, xampp, opencart, session-cookies

I want to set `HTTP` only flag in `xampp v3.2.2` i have installed `opencart v 2.3.0.2` on `xampp` and enable it in every `php.ini` but still not working you can also see this for [more information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777849/session-cookie-httponly-not-working)

Comment: How did you test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session.httponly option can be enabled by php.ini. To verify that it is working you will need to run:

```
phpinfo();
```

if the option is not there or set properly, then you are editing the wrong php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

For XAMPP on Ubuntu edit the file php.ini

```
/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

session.cookie_httponly=On
```

You can check its set using phpinfo();

http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.ini.php